Linux how to mount filesystem image file read/write using the loop option
I did a build of an Android GSI and it builds a system.img file:
$ file out/target/product/generic_arm64/system.img
out/target/product/generic_arm64/system.img: Linux rev 1.0 ext2 filesystem data, UUID=2c8eea3b-0bb2-46f9-a3d6-3e19c4968bff (extents) (large files) (huge files)

I then try to mount it read/write and it fails:
$ sudo mount -o loop out/target/product/generic_arm64/system.img /home/user/tmp/mnt
mount: /home/chrisk/tmp/mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop33, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

I then try to mount it read only and it succeeds:
$ sudo mount -o ro,loop out/target/product/generic_arm64/system.img /home/user/tmp/mnt
$ df
<stuff>
/dev/loop33       1928320    1862664     49272  98% /home/user/tmp/mnt
$ ls /home/user/tmp/mnt
acct        d              etc              metadata  postinstall             sys
apex        data           firmware         mnt       proc                    system
bin         data_mirror    init             odm       product                 system_dlkm
bugreports  debug_ramdisk  init.environ.rc  odm_dlkm  sdcard                  system_ext
cache       dev            linkerconfig     oem       second_stage_resources  vendor
config      dsp            lost+found       persist   storage                 vendor_dlkm

Can it not mount read/write because read/write needs more available space or something?
I want to add some small files to this image.
How do I mount this read/write ?
Thanks

The .img file is a fixed version of the source that you built it from, much the same as a .iso file, and it cannot dynamically grow or shrink.
If you have the source files that you created the .img file from, that is where you should be making any changes, before running the command to create a new .img file.
If you don't have the source that the .img was built from, you could:

Mount the .img read-only
Create a new directory
Copy the contents of the read-only mount into the directory
Make any changes you require within the directory
Use the relevant command to turn the contents of the directory in to a new .img file

Nick
